# Different width for Navigation Drawer in Tablet and Phone

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, tablet, android-screen-support

I was trying to implement material design for one of my project and [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), the following is mentioned,

> The maximum width of the nav drawer is 5 times the standard
>   increment (56dp on mobile and 64dp on tablet).

So I would like to know how to implement these width for navigation drawer for mobile and tablets. I want to make different width to respective devices, either phone or tablets.

I would love to use XML even if this also can be done using Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create values-sw600dp folder in your project and add dimens.xml file in it.
Define width in dimens.xml file of both values and values-sw600dp folder

For values-sw600dp/dimens.xml

```
    <resources>
    <dimen name="width">300dp</dimen></resources>
```

For values/dimens.xml

```
    <resources><dimen name="width">150dp</dimen>   </resources>
```

Call this in this manner

```
   android:layout_width="@dimens/width"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define two different dimens.xml corresponding to each device, then you just need to reference the dimen from your layouts

```
├── res
│   ├── values
│   │   ├── dimens.xml // Contains an item with 56dp
│   ├── values-sw600dp
│   │   ├── dimens.xml // Contains an item with 64dp
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, I did the following to fix the width of portrait and landscape modes, you can extend it to the display using ifs with display metrics.

```
    // Setup Navigation drawer
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    View drawer = findViewById(R.id.scrimInsetsFrameLayout);

    // Fix right margin to 56dp (portrait)
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = drawer.getLayoutParams();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        layoutParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels - (56 * Math.round(displayMetrics.density));
    }
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        layoutParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels + (20 * Math.round(displayMetrics.density)) - displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2;
    }
```

BTW in your case I should use the answers before (dimen for each version/mode/device).