# Navigation drawer item height issue on tablet

Tags: android

I am implementing `Navigation drawer` in my app. everything is fine. its working. but there is some design issue on tablet. item row height is different for both phone and tablet.

I am sharing screenshotfor both phone and tablet

[image]

[image]

The first image for tablet and second one for phone. how can i give same spacing like phone layout on tablet layout.

**Layout Xml:**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_items:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title="@string/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:dividerHeight="4dp"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Sign_in"
            android:title="@string/Sign_in"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:dividerHeight="20dp" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Sign_up"
            android:title="@string/Sign_Up"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_open_black_24dp"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Support"
            android:title="@string/Support"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_build_black_24dp"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Express_check_in"
            android:title="@string/Express_Check_in"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_all_black_24dp"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Write_review"
            android:title="@string/Write_review"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_write"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_HD_cash"
            android:title="@string/HD_cash"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_gift"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Refers_to_friends"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_group_add_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/Refers_to_friends" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Rate_US"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black_24dp"
            android:title="Rate our App" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sign_out"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_phonelink_lock_black_24dp"
            android:title="Sign Out"
            ></item>

    </group>

</menu>
```

**NavigationViewStyle:**

```
 <style name="NavigationViewStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbarText</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>




    </style>
```

Comment: post your code...

Comment: Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: I have posted code. have a look @Divyesh Patel

Comment: make layout folder for tablet and copy your layout in it. and try again

Comment: i have done it for both `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge`. but confused to how apply size for item row

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574506/different-width-for-navigation-drawer-in-tablet-and-phone

Comment: this solution is for width not for height of navigation drawer item@Divyesh Patel